# How to upload my Symfony project to shared hosting?

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony 3 app that I need to deploy to a shared hosting server - hostgator. I have copied all of the contents from the web folder into the public_html folder. I also copied all the other folders on the root of my directory. However, I does not run.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the proper permissions in particular the var/ folder, this is [described on this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup).

Also, if they use apache, you will have to set the owner:group of the web folder properly.

In Linux that is done easily by this command (from the root folder):

```
$ chown -R apache:apache web/
```

Try that out (you might need sudo access to run chown).

Comment: Yes, PuTTY is a good tool to use, presuming you can login via ssh.

Comment: Did my suggestions not work? If so, what problems did you run into?

Comment: Yes they have worked so far. The only problem is that respurces are not being loaded. I cleared the cache as well as installed all the assets.

Comment: Do you mean javascript files or image files? If so, maybe post a new question on that. It may be a different issue. Glad you got something working.

Comment: Yes, CSS files and JS. Thanks again for your time and help